# php sessions not carrying over from one page to the next

Tags: php, session

I've used sessions before on shared hosting and they were very simple. I'm now using Amazon and have linux server with the following configuration in php. The catch is session variables don't carry on from one page to the next:

```
session

Session Support enabled
Registered save handlers    files user memcached
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary

Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   Off Off
session.bug_compat_warn Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly On  On
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  604800  604800
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /var/lib/php/session    /var/lib/php/session
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

Sample Page: http://www.datingjapan.co/index.php

Code:
 index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
$_SESSION['domain'] = 'www.datinggirls.co';
print_r($_SESSION);
?>

<h1>This is the HTML</h1>
<a href="page.php">Visit W3Schools</a>
```

page.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['page2'] = 'page-two-data';
print_r($_SESSION);
?>

<h1>This is page 2</h2>
<a href="index.php">Visit Home Page</a>
```

Any advise... ?

thx

Comment: Are you sure that /var/lib/php/session is writable for the user the process is running as?

Comment: yes the user has write access... I'm running the sites down dynamic cloudfront (for speed) and just realized I didn't have pass cookies enabled... I'm currently testing this and will update this question once I have answers... thanks for you help :)

Comment: now its working... need to enable passing cookies on cloudfront... thankyou.!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time I ping your domain www.datingjapan.co it gives me a different IP.

Is your shared hosting on multiple cloud instances ? Probably.

Then the PHP session files may be stored localy on the first server that displayed the page "index". When you load the second page, you are on another server...

I agree with Peter, look at the amazon FAQ or support about how your session storage is synchronized (or not).

Comment: I hear what you are saying... currently I'm only running one server behind a load balancer so I've removed the multiple server factor...

Answer (score 1):

if you are using multiple servers they will each have their own session storage.  You should look at post on the amazon support forums about synchronizing the session storage between servers.

Edit:
Here's one such post on SO: [How to synchronize sessions using Amazon Web Services (AWS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715461/how-to-synchronize-sessions-using-amazon-web-services-aws)